# How to find the missing Akka Dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, dependency-management

I write a Scala project managed by SBT and I want to use TestKit package (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-testkit.html#TestKit).

In order to do it, I have to do the following imports:

```
import system.dispatcher
import akka.pattern.pipe
```

The problem is that I have to update build.sbt file in order to "bring" the needed dependencies. I tried to add the following dependency:

> "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit"                    % 2.4.2

and I still got an error for the lines:

```
import system.dispatcher
```

and

```
val probe = TestProbe()
```

Can you give me a hint on how to find the needed dependency given an import line?

Comment: did you do execute the `reload` command at the sbt terminal after making the change?   Do a `reload` and then execute `build` at the sbt terminal and see if its picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

`"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % 2.4.2 % Test`

`akka-http-teskit` is a test library, so you should be adding it to the `Test` scope.